# difficulty running BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pip, python-3.4, osx-yosemite

I have installed beautifulsoup4 using pip install. If I do pip list I get

```
Mac-mini:~ admin$ pip list
   beautifulsoup4 (4.3.2)
   pip (6.0.3)
   setuptools (7.0)
```

Yet when I call

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

I continue to get the error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from bs4 import _soup
ImportError: No module named 'bs4'
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled BS, I only have Python 3.4.2 on my computer and I am on OS 10.10.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you're using same version of python for pip and the python which you're using to run the program.

You can check the python version `pip` is using by issuing `pip -V` command:

```
$ pip -V
pip 1.5.6 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
$ pip3 -V
pip 1.5.6 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.4)
```

Comment: pip -V gives {pip 6.0.3 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages (python 3.2)} Would this be incompatible with 3.4?

Comment: @user1478335, Yes, it is incompatible. You should install `pip` for Python 3.4. Using `pip` for Python 3.2, it install package for Python 3.2 which cannot be used by Python 3.4.

Comment: How do I install pip for Python 3.4.2? Will I need to re-install beautifulsoup4?

Comment: @user1478335, Reference this: [installation - pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html). Use `python3.4` when you install `pip`. After installation is done, install `beautifulsoup4`. (Technically, it is not a reinstall, because it was not installed for Python 3.4)

Comment: In Python Framework, I have folders in versions 3.2, 3.3 and 3.4. Should I find beautiful soup installed somewhere here?

Comment: @user1478335, I don't get it. Did you install beautifulsoup4? `pip3.4 install beautifulsoup4`

Comment: @user1478335, It's 1 AM here. I'm going to bed. Leave a comment. I will reply.

Comment: Brilliant. At last it has worked. Thank you so much for your help!